# Is it possible to add symbols in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, vector, qgis-3

Is there any way so i can add symbols like ( <, > ,- ) in QGIS polygons/vectors so I can define for a example in which way is "this pipe of drainage leaking water"
Working in QGIS 3.2 Bonn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an additional style, using markers on top of your existing style. Markers can be rotated, either based on a standard value, or on a feature-specific value which has to be stored in its attributes.

[image]